# Extract Group Name based on the Cell content

Tags: excel, excel-formula, groupname

I have a set of data grouped and assigned 'Names' based on their categories which is something like Fruits: Apple, Orange, Kiwi.. and Vegetables: Tomato, Onion, Cabbage... Here Apple, Orange, Kiwi are defined with a Name called Fruits and similarly Tomato, Onion, Cabbage with a Name Vegetables.

In my sheet I have the cells Apple, Tomato etc., and would like to extract the Name assigned to it next to them.
I used =INDIRECT(Cell Address), unfortunately did not work. Is there any formula for this?

Comment: Do you have only these two group or many more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially if you want to avoid lengthy formulas and VBA, I suggest re-arranging your data a bit.

- Put the Name of the category in Row 1
- Format as **Table** and Name the **Table** something. *(I Named it `Foods`)*

Then your formula becomes simple:

```
=INDEX(Foods[#Headers],1,MAX((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D33,Foods))*COLUMN(Foods))))
```

Where `D33` contains the name of the food

[image]

*You could use a regular range and addressing, but using a table makes the names and ranges dynamic*

Comment: Thanks for the formula and solution. This solution appelas to me neat and short but unfortunately I will not be able to apply this to my sheet. Actually the data I have is generated through FILTER Formula and the Table cannot be inserted onto this data, as that leads to SPILL error.

Comment: @Ushay since you gave no examples of how your sheets are set up, I cannot give you more advice. However, it should not be difficult to adapt this concept to your actual data.

Comment: I did some tuning in my data sheet to apply your formula and it works well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be misunderstanding. But when referencing the cell address with indirect have you written it like so?

=INDIRECT(B2)
or
=INDIRECT("B2")

Comment: This formula will work if `B2` contains `Fruits` or `Vegetables` but op has `Apple` in `B2` cell and he wants group name based on B2 cell content.

Comment: Could you not create a reference table then and just do a lookup of what is in cell "B2" into the reference table.

Comment: @Tom_Foolery It would work, but I want to use the existing Name definitions

Answer (score 0):

If you many Named defined then this will be impractical. But you have only two names or few more then you can try below formula. Here ***Fruits*** named range is `A1:A3` and ***Vegetables*** named range is `B1:B3`.

```
=IF(SUM(--(Fruits=D1))>0,"Fruits",IF(SUM(--(Vegetables=D1))>0,"Vegetables","No Group"))
```

You may need array entry with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` for old versions of excel.

[image]

Comment: thanks for this formula. But this would be a lengthy ones for my case, as there are many Named groups

Comment: Then you may need to use `VBA` then.

Comment: VBA would be my last option, if it is not possible with the formula